# How to make the time in moment js live

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Hello i'm just looking to how to make time in moment js live.

i.e. I want to make the element update automatically

Comment: till now i have tried nothing, i just want to know how make time live.  I didn't found it in the docs of the website

Answer (score 14):

```
function update() {
  $('#clock').html(moment().format('D. MMMM YYYY H:mm:ss'));
}

setInterval(update, 1000);

<div id="clock">loading ...</div>
```